# How to split string URL by the '/' delimiter

Tags: python, html, dataframe, urllib

I have a code that used urllib to download pdf files from HTML link that store in a pandas dataframe.

The dataframe looks like below.

```
id   URL
1    https://www.pdf.com/first.pdf
2    https://www.pdf.com/second.pdf
3    https://www.pdf.com/third.pdf
:
:
N    https://www.pdf.com/numberN.pdf
```

My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('pdf list.csv')

#convert the URL column into a list
l = df['URL'].to_list()

#loop through the list to download pdf file from the HTML link
for link in l:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, "/Users/CodingStark/pdf/name of the pdf")
```

I have thousands of HTML links in my dataframe so it's not practical to give a name to each download pdf files. I am wondering are there any ways to automate this code in a way that I do not need to give a name to each pdf file. It is because when I open the html link, they already have a name given to that pdf file. I am just curious will I be able to use that name instead?
[Example link](http://www.justinholman.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/AgainstAllOdds_StudentGuide_Unit06.pdf.)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv('pdf list.csv')

#convert the URL column into a list
l = df['URL'].to_list()

#loop through the list to download pdf file from the HTML link
for link in l:
    filename = link.split('/')[-1]
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, f"/Users/CodingStark/pdf/{filename}")
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured this one as well but I am wondering will there be a way to use the actual name from the pdf file. Coz when I open the link, the name of the pdf will have a different name than the link provided. For example, the link may appear to be "https://www.pdf.com/first.pdf", we will assume the name is "first.pdf". But when I open the link, the actual name of the pdf appear at the right corner is "coding.pdf". So I am just curious are there any ways to use that name instead

Comment: From my understanding, the name you're referring to at the right corner is actually the 'title' of the PDF, present in the actual file's metadata. The actual name of the PDF file is what I have provided in my answer.

Comment: Ok got it. So I wont be able to use the title as the name?